# In Ruby on Rails 3.1, where do you put your own classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've created a class that I want to make available to the entire project for error responses.  Where would I put it in the RoR 3.1 directory structure?  In the lib/assets?  Also, is there information somewhere online for this?  I did a few searches and couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-model related code, I normally put in `/lib`.

If that gets busy, I'll probably create subdirectories of `/lib`
eg.

- `/lib/reports`
- `/lib/utils`
- `/lib/validators` (this could probably live in `/models/validators` too)

But more likely, I'll end up building a gem to handle the functionality.

This is kind of a question about working practices, so doesn't get documented so much,
but I'd encourage you to take a look at `The Rails 3 Way`, quite a hefty book, full of tutorials, and advice on good coding style.